# how to get all the rows that doesn't contain specific word?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**What I have?**

I got Dataframe looks like this:

```
       col1       |        col2         |      col3       .......
0       a                    b                   c
1       d             'not available'    'not available'    
2  'not available'           e                   f
3       g                    h                   i  
4       j                    k                   l
5       m              'not available'           n
.
.
.
```

with much more columns and rows

**What I want to get?**

I want to get all the rows that doesn't contain 'not available'
but if I use `pd.loc` I should write all the columns and I guess there is a much easier way to do so.

what is the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare all values for not equal by [`DataFrame.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ne.html) and then test if all `True`s per rows by [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) and filter in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df[df.ne('not available').all(axis=1)]
print (df1)
  col1 col2 col3
0    a    b    c
3    g    h    i
4    j    k    l
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `df.str.contains` with the column you want to search for with reverse boolean indexing using `~`

```
df_not_avail = df[~df['column'].str.contains('not available')]
```

`contains` would also allow you to use regex and look for patterns as well